# If \$\vec A=3\hat a_r+2\hat a_{\theta}-6\hat a_{\phi}\$, determine the vector component

Tags: electromagnetism

**If \$\begin{aligned}\\
\vec A=3\hat a_r+2\hat a_{\theta}-6\hat a_{\phi} \text{ and } \vec B=4\hat a_r&+3\hat a_{\phi}\\
\end{aligned}\\\$ determine a)\$\vec A.\vec B\$, b)\$|\vec A\times\vec B|\$, c)The vector component of \$\vec A\$ along \$\hat a_z\$ at \$(1, \pi/3, 5\pi/4)\$**

I have calculated a) and b) but I can't understand how to do c). Please anyone give me some hint.

Comment: Ask yourself what the result of a cross product and dot product really means. However, I've never had to do these in polar/spherical coordinates so I'm not sure if they just work the same way as in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Shouldn't be this a question for math overflow? Note that the math we electric engineers do are harder than the math mathematicians do. You should have asked it in math overflow.

Comment: First represent \$\hat{a}_z\$ in terms of \$\hat{a}_r\$, \$\hat{a}_\theta\$ and \$\hat{a}_\varphi\$. Do you know how to do that, given \$(1,\pi/3, 5\pi/4)\$ ? hint : \$\hat{a}_z\$ doesn't depend on \$\hat{a}_\varphi\$. See this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) which will help you with the first step.